# Change GotoRecord Method To RecordsetClone

Tags: ms-access, recordset

I need to change the GotoRecord in This Code To RecordsetClone Method Because i Have a problem With GotoRecord which ruining everything for me

```
Dim sql As DAO.Recordset
Set sql = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TblPoMaterials", dbOpenDynaset)
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst    ' THE PROBLEM IS HERE
For m = 1 To T8

With sql
.AddNew
!PONumber = T7
!MaterialCode = Code1
!MaterialName = T1
!ProductionDate = T6
!Shift = "none"
!cons = T2
!AdditionPercent = Text324
!MaterialType = Text300
!OrderQty = T3
.Update
End With
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext 

Next m
MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, "Saved successfully"
```

The Form Is Unbound Continuous Form with this code

```
SELECT Bom.productcode, Bom.code, Bom.Item, Bom.cons, Bom.BomNumber, [Item Names].Type, Bom.Remarks FROM [Item Names] INNER JOIN Bom ON [Item Names].code = Bom.code WHERE (((Bom.productcode)=Forms!FrmNewPo!t0) And ((Bom.BomNumber)=Forms!FrmNewPo!Bom));
```

Comment: If you use UNBOUND forms, there are no records to "GoTo". In which case, RecordsetClone will not be useful either. If form is UNBOUND then what is that SQL statement for?

Comment: The Continuous part (Detail) record source is the SQL Statement , But the header has too many unbound textbox which appended by the SQL Statement in the code .

Comment: it could be easier if the site has some sort of attachments system , would save alot of time explaining

Comment: I strongly recommend you consider form/subform arrangement and eliminate problem code. Other forums do facilitate attaching files.

Comment: Thanks man i will think about your suggestion , About other forums with attachments is it allowed to give me some links ?

Comment: It's against SO model but can put links to downloadable file in SO. Other forums actually allow attaching file to post. Such as accessforums.net, utteraccess.com, access-programmers.co.uk.